# Как правильно сделать передачу через std::forward<T> объекта std::function

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++14, std-forward

Пробую сделать передачу объекта `std::function`, но после передачи член класса `std::function`, куда производилась передача остаётся пустым. Как мне правильно это реализовать?

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
public:
    template <typename T>
    void Subscribe(T&& OwnFunctor) {
        OwnFunctor = std::forward<T>(OwnFunctor);
    };
    int Callback(int val) {
        return OwnFunctor(val);
    }
private:
    std::function<int(int)> OwnFunctor;
};

int Bat(int val){
    return val * val;
}

void main() {
    Foo foo;
    std::function<int(int)> Functor = Bat;
    foo.Subscribe(Functor); // Попытка передать lval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    foo.Subscribe(std::move(Functor));// Попытка передать rval
    cout << foo.Callback(5) << endl;;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стоит сообразить, что `Subscribe` - не конструктор, а присваивание - не инициализация члена, так что в

```
OwnFunctor = std::forward<T>(OwnFunctor);
```

оба `OwnFunctor` - один и то же переданный параметр, не имеющий никакого отношения к полю... и заменить это на

```
this->OwnFunctor = std::forward<T>(OwnFunctor);
```

как все встает на свои места...

Comment: Тупейшая ошибка, спасибо вам.